# Using focus on elements inside contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to use the following code to reference anything focused inside my contenteditable div, which has an id of `rt`:

```
var lastfocused;
$("#rt *").focus(function () {
  lastfocused = $(this);
});
```

For some reason, lastfocused always equals `$("#rt");`, but never anything else which may be inside the contenteditable div. How do I make it so that anything focused inside the contenteditable div will be stored in the `lastfocused` variable?

Comment: can you post the markup, it worked for me with inputs inside

Comment: @agreco My markup's right there. All other referencing is as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is elsewhere. The above code perfectly works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/8hZWq/

**EDIT**

If the children elements aren't inputs as you said, but divs - the focus() method is not applicable to them, as it works only for input, textareas, select etc.

You can also use .click() instead of focus() to store the reference to the last clicked element. Bear in mind though, it also depends to the structure of your elements.

For example if you have multiple levels of containers within children divs, the `#ID *` selector will actually trigger multiple times each level of children starting from the #ID.

If you like to store reference to only the first level of children of the #ID, you should use `#ID > *` selector to refer only direct children.

If you like to store the reference to only the very element that was clicked upon regardless of it's level in relation to the container, you should use click event target reference instead:

```
var clicked;
$('#ID').click(function(event){
   clicked = $(event.target);
});
```

Comment: but my problem was with a contenteditable div, not with an input field.

Comment: but div doesn't have focus, does it?

Comment: yes it does. any element can have focus as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: you are wrong then. only input controls can have focus, like textarea, input, select, buttons etc. What are you trying to do?

Comment: oh ok then my bad. Then how can I do it using `.click()`? I'm sure every element can have `.click()` applied to it.

Comment: yeah, just replace .focus to .click and it will store the reference to the last clicked element

Comment: Your answer helped me think of a better one. Thank you.

Comment: Actually any contenteditable element can have focus, as can any element with a `tabindex` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your problem is because of variable declaration out of the function. Setting it in, in each focus event the 'lastfocused' variable will be re-assigned.

I came later, but if i arrive here someone else can.

Do this:

```
$("#rt *").focus(function () {
   var lastfocused = $(this);
});
```